# Reflections on Serialization APIs in D

Tags: c++, serialization, d, boost-serialization, phobos

In the road to develop a new kind of search engine that caches types, statistics, etc about files and directories I'm currently trying to implement persistent caching of my internal directory tree using `msgpack-d`:

Why doesn't `msgpack-d` and, from what I can see also, `std.serialization` (Orange) support implementing *both* packing and unpacking through one common template (member) function overload like **Boost.Serialization** does?. For example containers can be serialized using this concise and elegant template member function

```
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, const uint version) {
        for (const auto& e : *this) { ar & e; }
    }
```

This halves the code size aswell as removes the risk of making the `pack` and `unpack` go out of sync. Have I missed any big cons with using this approach or hasn't this approach simply not been prioritized?

Comment: https://github.com/atilaneves/cerealed fullfils most of my needs.